# Does DBUnit DatabaseSequenceFilter work for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, dbunit

I'm dumping the whole contents of my MySQL database to file with DBUnit, and getting `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ...` when reading back in.

The tables are being written in alphabetical order, even though I use the DatabaseSequenceFilter to reorder them by dependency.

```
filter = new DatabaseSequenceFilter(connection);
dataset = new FilteredDataSet(filter, connection.createDataSet());
FlatXmlDataSet.write(dataset, w)
```

The database clearly has the foreign key constraints specified (I can see them, and they wouldn't fail on import if they weren't there).

Has anyone seen DatabaseSequenceFilter working for MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Debug to see which query produced this exception. Connect to db and check which constraint it is about. Show example log, it will be easier to help.

Comment: Bless you, but I think the moment has passed